# Is memcached’s cachedump expected to be consistent?

Tags: macos, memcached

I’ve read many times on Stack Overflow and elsewhere that `stats cachedump` was unsupported, soon-to-be-removed, limited to dumping 1MB, etc. Yet, as I’m just starting to play with memcached, I’d find it very convenient to list all (very few) keys I’m setting in development.

However, what I’m currently getting are extremely inconsistent, barely useful results. See this example session where I clear everything then set three very small items (empty lines added for clarity):

```
flush_all

set key1 0 0 3
aaa
STORED

set key2 0 0 3
bbb
STORED

set key3 0 0 3
ccc
STORED
```

Then `stats items` says there are 3 items in slab 1, as expected:

```
stats items
STAT items:1:number 3
STAT items:1:number_hot 0
STAT items:1:number_warm 0
STAT items:1:number_cold 3
STAT items:1:age_hot 0
STAT items:1:age_warm 0
STAT items:1:age 3
STAT items:1:evicted 0
STAT items:1:evicted_nonzero 0
STAT items:1:evicted_time 0
STAT items:1:outofmemory 0
STAT items:1:tailrepairs 0
STAT items:1:reclaimed 0
STAT items:1:expired_unfetched 0
STAT items:1:evicted_unfetched 0
STAT items:1:evicted_active 0
STAT items:1:crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT items:1:crawler_items_checked 0
STAT items:1:lrutail_reflocked 57
STAT items:1:moves_to_cold 23
STAT items:1:moves_to_warm 20
STAT items:1:moves_within_lru 0
STAT items:1:direct_reclaims 0
STAT items:1:hits_to_hot 0
STAT items:1:hits_to_warm 0
STAT items:1:hits_to_cold 23
STAT items:1:hits_to_temp 0
END
```

But when I try to list all items in slab 1, results are totally inconsistent. Often listing 2 arbitrary keys out of 3, but sometimes listing all 3 (which proves the data is all there and hasn’t been evicted):

```
stats cachedump 1 0
ITEM key1 [3 b; 0 s]
ITEM key2 [3 b; 0 s]
END

stats cachedump 1 0
ITEM key3 [3 b; 0 s]
ITEM key2 [3 b; 0 s]
END

stats cachedump 1 0
ITEM key2 [3 b; 0 s]
ITEM key1 [3 b; 0 s]
END

stats cachedump 1 0
ITEM key2 [3 b; 0 s]
ITEM key1 [3 b; 0 s]
ITEM key3 [3 b; 0 s]
END

stats cachedump 1 0
ITEM key2 [3 b; 0 s]
ITEM key1 [3 b; 0 s]
ITEM key3 [3 b; 0 s]
END

stats cachedump 1 0
ITEM key2 [3 b; 0 s]
ITEM key3 [3 b; 0 s]
END
```

What to make of this? Is that the expected behavior?

I am using the latest memcached version 1.5.8 on macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/issues/405), the right way to dump all keys in recent versions of memcached is with `lru_crawler metadump 1` (or `lru_crawler metadump all`).